# Auto-increment setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1) not working after getting response from API call in React

Tags: reactjs

`setPage` count not updating after getting response from API call in React Js

Actually, I'm working on the scroll event; when the user scrolls down, I need to send a request and append the response to existing data using the page count value. When I tried to update the page count value by `setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1)` after getting the result from the response, every time the page value showed 1 (the initial assigned value), I didn't know what the issue was in my code. Please give me any workaround methods. Thanks in advance.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "../configure/config";
const InfiniteScroll = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const hr = props.apiKeys.data.__qhrkey;
  const toe = props.apiKeys.data.__token;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); // Initial data fetch
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    if (loading) return; // Prevent multiple requests
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    const url = "/services/getScheduleDetails";
    const params = { __hr: hr, __toe: toe, __p: page };
    const api = API_URL + url;
    axios
      .post(api, params)
      .then((response) => {
        setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...response.data]); // Append new data to the existing data
        setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1); // Increment the page count # HERE I'M GETTING ISSUE
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !==
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
      loading
    ) {
      return;
    }
    fetchData(); // Fetch more data when the user reaches the bottom of the page
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.title}</div>
      ))}
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScroll;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the function `fetchData` is created once when the component is mounted, and it doesn't get refreshed when there's a state change. So although the state is changing correctly (I believe, you could add logs to verify), the page defined here `const params = { __hr: hr, __toe: toe, __p: page };` never changes.

One way of overcoming this would be to use the `useRef` hook instead, like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "../configure/config";
const InfiniteScroll = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const page = useRef(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const hr = props.apiKeys.data.__qhrkey;
  const toe = props.apiKeys.data.__token;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); // Initial data fetch
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    if (loading) return; // Prevent multiple requests
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    const url = "/services/getScheduleDetails";
    const params = { __hr: hr, __toe: toe, __p: page.current };
    const api = API_URL + url;
    axios
      .post(api, params)
      .then((response) => {
        setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...response.data]); // Append new data to the existing data
        page.current += 1 // Increment the page count # HERE I'M GETTING ISSUE
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !==
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
      loading
    ) {
      return;
    }
    fetchData(); // Fetch more data when the user reaches the bottom of the page
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.title}</div>
      ))}
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScroll;
```